# Adding a 'level pack' to an existing iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm working on an iphone game that I plan to submit to the app store soon but there's one thing that I havent figured out yet. My game has multiples levels for the player to pass (obtaining scores along the way) to complete the campaign. My question is: can I add more levels to the app later through 'level packs', as in, not updating the game itself with those new levels but allowing the user to download/buy the packs separately if they want?

I want to do something like the shooter games for consoles do: have the original game at a price and the map packs (DLC) at a smaller price, but still separate. I understand that I could just update the app with the new levels in it but then the users that had the app purchased before that would get the new levels for free by just updating.

I dont want to have multiple versions of the game (like Angry Birds Original, Seasons, Rio, etc...) if can just have one, with several packs on the side.

Comment: While these answers are correct, be aware that Apple does not allow ANY code to be downloaded as part of an in-app purchase. Apple's own guidance on this is to include all the functionality in the app your user downloads and then unlock it using in-app purchase. If you can do it strictly with downloading data, then this is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In App Purchases are a perfect fit for you. Read about them [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). One of the example use cases is:

> A game that offers new environments (levels) to explore.

Once the App Store validates the purchase, you can allow the app access to a generated download link or something, and download `.lvl` files or similar to the local filesystem, which your game can then search for in a known directory and list them if they're available.

Comment: @ArkReversed: Also do your research : there are lots of restrictions and stuff when you use In-App purchasing. Also, Apple takes a big cut.

Comment: +1 You're right. Apple takes a 30% cut of the profits when you use this model, but they've recently [patented in-app purchasing](http://www.bnet.com/blog/technology-business/apple-looks-to-burn-google-with-3rd-party-in-app-purchase-patent/13169) so there's little else you can do really. Assuming this patent is accepted, if you were to implement your own custom solution they could sue for patent infringement.

Comment: jeez *facepalm*. If they really wanted to play that, there are so many instances of prior art... but that's another discussion for another forum :)

Comment: Ok I see. Using in app purchases the game could be easily "unlock" the levels in itself. However you guys dont seem sold on this way of adding content. If you wanted to do something similar (add more levels to some game) how would you go about it? :)

Comment: The only way to have users purchase levels is to use in-app purchases. It is against Apple's Review Guidelines for iOS to use any other method inside your app. And if you want to put the payment portal outside of your app, you're not allowed to put any kind of link or indicator inside of the app, so you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in-app purchases. The user buys more packs, and when the purchase is successful, you can either unlock them using `NSUserDefaults`, or download the levels from your server.

NSUserDefaults:

```
//in-app purchase has completed successfully
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Level Pack 1 Bought"];

//checking if level packs bought so that you can display them to the user
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey@"Level Pack 1 Bought"] == YES) {

    //unlock the packs, such as unhiding a button that links to them, etc

}
```